# Extract part of composite sort key in DynamoDB projection

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a composite sorting key as "123#xyz". I want to return only the first part of this key to the user.
Is it possible to use projection in a query to extract substring of a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, projection expression can only return the entire value. What you need to do is split those values manually into two separate attributes which you can later decide to project.

| PK | SK | partA | partB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| somepk | 123#xyz | 123 | xyz |

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t substring on a projection like that.

When using a composite sort key, I like having the plain values as their own attributes unless I’m really worried about space. That design would help you here.